# Privoxy VS Polipo

Tags: configuration, proxy, socks, torsocks, privoxy

I'm trying to share a SocksPort (SocksPort 192.168.0.14:10001) with a mobile device. The mobile device only supports HTTP proxies. It seems polipo used to be supported/promoted[1] by the torproject but based on general search queries, privoxy seems like the better candidate. Can someone weigh the pros/cons of the two and perhaps make a strong argument for one.

[1] https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/polipo

Answer (score 2):

Well, privoxy and polipo are *basically* even: they both have filtering systems inside them, both are HTTP-to-SOCKS tools. In the last beta of tor you have a HTTPS proxy embedded in tor itself, so I'd rather recommend you to use an embedded one. To do so you should add [HTTPTunnelPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en#HTTPTunnelPort) directive to your torrc like this:

```
HTTPTunnelPort 127.0.0.1:8118
```

Comment: Can you elaborate here? Are you saying tor now has a builtin HTTP proxy feature? Can you link to some documentation and/or edit your answer to offer some setup instructions?

Comment: take a look here https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/plain/ChangeLog  and there https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en#HTTPTunnelPort

Answer (score 0):

Polipo is a caching proxy. It's goal was to reduce traffic (but in modern world with modern browsers it is nearly useless). Polipo is no longer maintained. Sad but true.
Privoxy is a filtering non-caching proxy.